# How to access constructor function from object by using this

Tags: javascript, function, object

In this example. I need to update friends list from object function.

```
var MyClass = function () {
    this.friends = [];
    this.runtime = {
        add: function (name) {
            this.friends.push(name);
        }
    }
};

MyClass.prototype.AddFriend = function (name) {
    this.runtime.add(name);
};

MyClass.prototype.GetFriends = function () {
    return this.friends;
};
```

How it's possible?

Comment: Urg. Why don't you just do `this.friends.push(name)` from that function? You're running into all kinds of crazy context issues there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/497418

Comment: @Andy I know that. But in my big project. I can't change total code. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the bind() method:

```
var MyClass = function () {
    this.friends = [];
    this.runtime = {
        add: function (name) {
            this.friends.push(name);
        }.bind(this)
    }
};

MyClass.prototype.AddFriend = function (name) {
    this.runtime.add(name);
};

MyClass.prototype.GetFriends = function () {
    return this.friends;
};
```

Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: No problem. Although as @Andy rightly pointed out you should actually be using this.friends.push(name)...but if you really can't avoid scoping your functions like that then it will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comments, it makes much more sense to use `this.friends.push(name)`, but if you really have to use that odd runtime function, then you need to save a copy of `this` to a new variable:

```
var MyClass = function () {
    var _this = this;
    this.friends = [];
    this.runtime = {
        add: function (name) {
            _this.friends.push(name);
        }
    }
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/vk1qa0wj/)